# wso2 API Manager API's lost

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I was using API manager ,identity server and i have a lot of API's and users being created. I rebuilt my EC2 instance [created a new instance to change java installation ] and pointed to the same database which was existing.Everything is fine ;but none of my API's are being listed. I can see the same users,roles and application. But my API's are missing.
Which table can i use for verifying the API's existing? Which is the data source i should verify? What could have possibly gone wrong.The only difference between older machine and new machine is the java installation changed from open jdk to oracle jdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be an indexing issue. Follow these steps and see if it resolves the problem.

1) Backup and delete `<APIM_HOME>/solr` directory.

2) Open `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml`

3) Change the value of `<lastAccessTimeLocation>` like this.

```
<lastAccessTimeLocation>/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime_2</lastAccessTimeLocation>
```

3) Restart the server.